# How to find the truth values of something like this? If 3×5 = 15, then 3+5=10

Tags: logic

The question was to find the truth values of if 3×5=15, then 3+5=10?

Is the truth table corresponding to p $\implies $q ?

Or is it more complicated than that? Do we have to consider something like $(p \land q \implies r ) \implies (p \lor q \implies s) ?$

Comment: What?? I don't get it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression $3\times5=15\implies3+5=10$ is equivalent to the expression $true \implies false$.

This expression has $0$ Boolean arguments, hence the size of its truth table is $2^0=1$.

The only value in the truth table of this expression is of course $false$.

---

For non-constant $p$ and $q$, the truth table of the expression $p \implies q$ consists of $2^2=4$ entries:

```
 p | q | v
---|---|---
 0 | 0 | 1
---|---|---
 0 | 1 | 1
---|---|---
 1 | 0 | 0  this zero is the truth table of your expression
---|---|---
 1 | 1 | 1
```